# DRF3 Creating nested serializers on m2m-relation

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a User-model and a Concert-model. The Concert-model has a m2m-field to the User-model. In the Concert-views, I want a list of dictionaries of the User's with a relation to the Concert-model. This is what I got:

**models.py**

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    objects = UserManager()
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 255, default = "")
    date_added = models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True, db_index=True)
    (more but irrelevant)

class Concert(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 255)
    technicians = models.ManyToManyField(User)
```

**serializers.py**

```
class ConcertListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    technicians = UserDetailSerializer(
            many=True,
            read_only=True,
            source='concert_set'
        )

    class Meta:
        model = models.Concert
        fields = [
            'name',
            'technicians',
            'id',
        ]

class UserDetailSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = [
            'name',
            'email',
            'id',
        ]
```

What I expect is the technicians-field in the ConcertListSerializer to be a list of dictionaries with name, email and id of the users. Why does it not provide this like the [DRF Documentation on Nested Serializers](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#nested-relationships) says it will .. ?

Answer (score 3):

why you add `source` you use the same serializer field as model field, just remove it.

```
class ConcertListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    technicians = UserDetailSerializer(
            many=True,
            read_only=True,
        )
```

Comment: I tried this first, but it gave nothing. What is weird is that the technicians field is not showing up in the view at all. Not even as a field set to None...

Comment: can you add your real code of the serializers, because current you show could not work

Comment: I have only removed some of the entries in the field-list and removed the corresponding attributes in the models.

Comment: your `UserDetailSerializer` should be declare before `ConcertListSerializer` do you declare it one time in the serializers?

Comment: UserDetailSerializer is imported from another django app. The User and it's serializers is in another app alltogether. They are both imported in to the app that Concert is in.